# Does it make sense to put my website (inetpub) files on a shared drive?

Tags: windows, azure, iis, deployment, cloud

I have a hosting setup running in azure with a load balancer and VM's running IIS, my application uses data like pictures etc, which are stored on a network share, so all VM replications can access it. I was just thinking that each VM has IIS configured, would it be a smart thing to put my deployment files (inetpub folder) also on the share, this way when updating my website I only have to update 1 fileset on the share as opposed to each VM's inetpub folder.

Comment: Side-question: Why don't you store your static files in a CDN / Blob Storage?

Comment: Because the (legacy) application uses a direct UNC file path to access photos etc so to enable that I'm using the Azure File service. If I understood correctly to use blobs directly there would have be an extra layer of code handling the blob conversion/accesssing.

Comment: ok, never mind. One thing to mention is that the directory permissions probably will change if you share the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea - not sure what the performance would be like.  A more conventional approach would be to use Cloud Services, or (newer/better) use VM Scale Sets.  Create a base image with IIS on it, and package your application code in a VM Extension.  That way, when Azure autoscales your VMSS, it will deploy your code to that VM for you.  When you want to update your code, you just refresh the extension.  The VMSS can be deployed with an ARM template (see [Managing VM Scale Sets with ARM and Powershell](https://russellyoung.net/2016/09/01/managing-vm-scale-sets-vmss-with-powershell-and-arm-templates/)) for some more info on that piece - for the deployment of applications to VMSS via extensions, see [Deploy an App on Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app/).

You can then automate the deployment of your code as part of your build/release management process, should be easier to scale and manage than a couple of fixed VMs.

ps. VMSS come with their own internal load balancer as well

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that :)